# InAppSettingsKit UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, inappsettingskit

How do you add a UIWebView (to load a live site, not an HTML page) to show as a sub-view of IASK?

I see this example in the sample app, but it is using a static local page.

[image: IASK sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the http:// URL of the page into the File key instead of your local file name.

Comment: Yea that's what I ended up doing. Unfortunately there's not too much flexibility there, I'll probably end up creating a custom webview. Same for Mail compose, i.e. it's not possible to set the subject dynamically.

Comment: Sure, you can write your own custom view controller or subclass IASK's. For mail you can also use custom mailto links in the webview which could be generated dynamically by the web server (or Javascript).

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a custom view controller. Follow up question - is there a way to set a button to have a disclosure icon?

Comment: Please post a new question and link it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211157/inappsettingskit-set-a-button-to-have-a-disclosure-icon