# InAppSettingsKit - set a button to have a disclosure icon?

Tags: ios, iphone, inappsettingskit

Is there a way to set a button to have a disclosure icon, similar to the child pane specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box if you're using `IASKButtonSpecifier`. Your options are:

A) implement `-tableView:cellForSpecifier:` in your delegate and customize the returned cell. You first call super, then set the `accessoryType` of the cell to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

B) use `PSChildPaneSpecifier` combined with a custom view controller.